# Piscina natural à base de uma cachoeira

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, sinônimos, definição

Continuando a empreitada de criação de legendas, cheguei noutro impasse, mas desta vez, ao invés de um problema de História, é de Geografia.

Estou com dificuldades para encontrar o nome correto da "base" de uma cachoeira. Temos o rio acima, a cachoeira em si, e aquela porção de água que se forma na base dela.

Na [Wikipédia em Inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunge_pool) tem um artigo falando a respeito sobre o assunto mas, obviamente, referente à expressão original em inglês **Plunge pool**

Traduzir essa palavra não fica convincente o bastante pois, na minha opinião, **piscina** não exemplifica muito bem, afinal uma "plunge pool", seja qual for a expressão correspondente em Português mais adequada é, basicamente, o solo, às vezes rochoso, sendo de certa forma esculpido pela alta pressão da cachoeira.

Eu até consegui um sinônimo, [chapinheiro](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chapinheiro), mas o significado é ainda menos condizente com o acidente geográfico em questão.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes usar ***pego, poço ou poção da cachoeira***. Qualquer destas palavras — [*pego* (|é| Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pego), [*poço* (Priberam 4)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/po%C3%A7o) ou [*poção* (Priberam 2)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/po%C3%A7%C3%A3o) — significa o ponto mais fundo de um rio ou lago. Portanto não tem de ser necessariamente na base duma cachoeira. Mas de acordo com o [artigo sobre o *plunge pool* na Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunge_pool), na base da cachoeira forma-se uma cova mais funda do que o leito do rio a jusante. Portanto *pego da cachoeira*, *poção da cachoeira*, etc. identificam claramente essa cova.

Em Portugal, ***pego*** é a palavra mais comum. Vejam o [Pego da Rainha](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC5HAYH_pego-da-rainha-macao?guid=646b7bf3-6eac-4d8b-b81e-e8a4e5eedb3c) perto de [Mação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%A7%C3%A3o), o [Pego do Mourão](http://fotos-e-passeios.blogspot.pt/2012/03/pego-do-mourao-ancos-sintra-ii.html) perto de [Sintra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintra), o [Pego do Vigário](http://www.sulinformacao.pt/2015/07/queda-do-vigario-em-alte-sem-agua-por-causa-da-seca/) perto de [Loulé](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loul%C3%A9) ou o [Pego do Inferno](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=319384) perto de [Tavira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavira). Já no Brasil (com agradecimentos ao @rslemos) parece ser mais comum ***poço*** e ***poção***. Vejam o [Poção do Córrego Grande](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/6274635) na [ilha de Santa Catarina](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilha_de_Santa_Catarina), o [Poção da Maromba](http://www.portalviscondedemaua.com/pocao_da_maromba.asp) em [Visconde de Matuá (RJ)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visconde_de_Mau%C3%A1_(Resende)), o [Poção de Paranapiacaba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKoU5cQ1HMg) em [Paranapiacaba (SP)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranapiacaba) ou o [Poço Encantado](http://cachoeirapocoencantado.tur.br/) perto da cidade de [Alto Paraíso (Goiás)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto_Para%C3%ADso_de_Goi%C3%A1s).

Além destas palavras, temos [*lagamar* (Priberam 1)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lagamar), que também vem nos dicionários como sinónimo de *pego* ou *poção*, mas eu não a consegui encontrar associada a cachoeiras.

*Pego*, mesmo sendo a única das palavras que eu conhecia com este significado, não é uma palavra muito usada,  e eu lembro-me, ou penso que me lembro, de a ouvir com o ***e*** fechado, ***ê***; os dicionários dizem que é com ***e*** aberto, ***é***;  mas [este site com fotos do Pego do Inferno, no Algarve,](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=319384) escreve *Pêgo*. Possivelmente existem as duas pronúncias. E fica aqui um foto do dito cujo.

[image: Pego do Inferno, perto de Tavira, Algarve]
[Pego do Inferno](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=319384), perto de Tavira, Algarve

Comment: Eu gostei de "poço da cachoeira".

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não conhecia *poço* com o significado de *pego*, mas vários dicionários confirmam, e compreende-se.

Comment: Na Chapada Diamantina, locais e não locais chamam aquele lago de "poço" ou "poção".

Comment: @Jacinto eu também só conheço cachoeira vindo do BR. Eu costumava usar cascata ou catarata(no caso de ser grande) para o mesmo efeito. "fomos até à cascata dar um mergulho"

Comment: Gostei de **pego**, mas eu acho que com o acento, *pêgo*, ficaria graficamente mais apresentável, além de distinguir melhor para o telespectador que não se trata da conjugação do verbo "pegar". Existe alguma fonte que afirme que o acento circunflexo realmente não existe?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Tudo o que eu posso dizer é que os dicionários dizem que é pronunciado ***é***. Mas atenção, na grafia atual é *pego*, sem acento, independentemente de ser pronunciado com ***e*** aberto ou fechado. Como eu acabei de acrescentar, no Brasil parece usar-se mais *poço* e *poção*. Mas eu econtrei *pego* em sentido figurado em autores brasileiros, *pego das minha angústias* e coisas assim. E *pego* vem também nos dicionários brasileiros.

Comment: @rslemos Obrigado pela informação. Já descobri vários poços e poções no Brasil. Aparentemente estão espalhados pelo país todo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ah! então foi por uma questão de coerência que preferiste *poço da cachoeira*: *poço* é usado com este significado no Brasil, mas não encontrei indícios que *pego* seja (para além de vir no dicionário).

Comment: Então, no passado, era **pêgo**, com acento e agora não é mais, certo? Posso ser mais antiquado quanto à isso, mas pra mim esse Acordo Gramatical estragou várias palavras, sendo assim não me importaria em manter o acento.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Já se chegou a escrever *pégo*: por exemplo, no dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913 (Portugal); e também [nesta publicação brasileira de 1950](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4JhoAAAAMAAJ&q=clavina+no+fundo+do+pego&dq=clavina+no+fundo+do+pego&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE-ZfGwOTNAhXJRhQKHZyCAZgQ6AEIHTAA); mas esses acentos já tinham sido abolidos antes do Acordo Ortográfico de 2009 (tenho vários dicionários anteriores com *pego* sem acento. É possível que a pronúncia com ***e*** fechado seja um regionalismo do sul de Portugal.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Mas já encontrei *pego* usado no sentido literal por autores brasileiros. Para além do link anterior, temos [esta passagem (refere-se é ao mar e não rio) do José de Alencar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YbZcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&dq=%22O+mesmo+pego,+insond%C3%A1vel+abismo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMtpWXweTNAhULPBQKHT8wD6MQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22O%20mesmo%20pego%2C%20insond%C3%A1vel%20abismo%22&f=false)

Comment: Que coisa, se não se pode com os loucos, junte-se à eles XD

Comment: Jacinto, o "poção" é da "Maromba".  Local muito aprazível, por sinal.

Answer (score 0):

Se sua legenda só precisa explicar aquele "pequeno lago" formado pela queda da cachoeira.

Minha sugestão seria: "Piscina d'água que a cachoeira forma".

Se você precisa de um termo técnico-científico sobre aquela solo que o "plunge pool" fica, sugiro procurar em livro de geografia da sua língua materna, pra saber se existe um nome para aquela formação e depois traduzir para português.

Comment: De fato, é um termo técnico sim